# How to set correct Phaser Weapon position

Tags: javascript, position, phaser-framework

I am trying to use Weapon class, and I found some problem.

Here is my code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(640, 360, Phaser.AUTO);

var GameState = {
    preload: function(){
        game.load.image('player', 'assets/images/player.png');
        game.load.image('enemyBody', 'assets/images/enemyBody.png');
        game.load.image('bullet', 'assets/images/bullet.png');
    },
    create: function(){
        this.player = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'player');
        this.enemy = game.add.sprite(500, 200, 'enemyBody');

        //this.makeShoot();

        this.enterKey = this.game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.ENTER);
        this.enterKey.onDown.add(this.pressEnterKey, this);

    },
    pressEnterKey: function(){
        this.makeShoot();
    },
    makeShoot: function(){
        this.player.rotation = this.game.physics.arcade.angleBetween(this.player, this.enemy);

        this.bullet = game.add.weapon(1, 'bullet');
        this.bullet.trackSprite(this.player, 0, 0, true);
        this.bullet.fire();
    }
};

game.state.add('GameState', GameState);
game.state.start('GameState');
```

When the code is executing, after the FIRST press Enter a bullet appears at (0, 0), then bullets appear at the player position.

If I remove the comment from commented line it will works perfect.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: post more context... it now can be anything with up or downstream code.

Answer (score 0):

Weapon and bullet are two separate things. You need to initialize your weapon instance in the `create()` method and then just spawn bullets in the `makeShoot()` method, like this:

```
create: function(){
    this.player = ...
    this.weapon = this.add.weapon(1, 'bullet');
    this.weapon.trackSprite(this.player, 0, 0, true);
    ...
},

makeShoot: function(){
    this.player.rotation = this.physics.arcade.angleBetween(this.player, this.enemy);

    this.weapon.fire();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem by changing the version of phaser framework to 2.6.2. But your answer is very useful for me, I will rewrite my code.